# AWS lambda concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I was trying to estimate AWS lambda using AWS pricing calculator, but I am confused.

If I estimate `Provisioned concurrency` section than is `Service settings` section mandatory to estimate ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your Lambda functions exceed the provisioned concurrency, the excess executions will be charged at the normal rate (ie. the rates shown in the `Service settings` section). You don't need estimations in both sections if you plan to keep everything within your provisioned concurrency limits. However if you only provision at a certain baseline and your function is expected to scale beyond that, your estimate should include the excess executions in the `Service settings` section.